# Facebook Like button won't work with subdomains

Tags: facebook, subdomain, facebook-like

So I've got my Facebook app ID for subdomain dot sitename dot com, popped in the javascript and whatnot at the bottom of the page and threw in the button where I want it on the site. The Like button shows up, recognizes me as a Facebook user. Wonderful.

But when I click on the "Like" button, instead of liking subdomain.sitename.com/blah, it "Likes" www.sitename.com/blah, thus giving an error.

I've hardcoded http://subdomain.sitename.com in, used a variable set to http:// subdomain dot sitename.com, etc. Regardless of what I do, it's somehow changed to www dot sitename.com/blah

So the like button doesn't work. Any suggestions on what the problem may be? Even when I use Facebook's lint it still throws up an exception error, saying www.sitename.com/blah doesn't work.

$facebooksite contains the subdomain dot sitename dot com. The rest is the link to a particular video. Yet for some reason, it still changes $facebooksite into www dot sitename dot com

Code here:

```
<script src="connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></… href="<?php echo $facebooksite; ?>/video/<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" font="lucida grande" show-faces="false" width="300"></fb:like
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was in the meta tags, which were set to display www.sitename.com for some reason. I changed them and now everything's running smoothly.